# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token

Tags: arrays, c, struct, embedded, game-boy-advance

I'm trying to create a 1bpp bitmap font for Game Boy Advance in C, essentially I want to create a consecutive region of ROM data that's indexed by (ASCII CODE - 32)*8. So far, I'm getting this error message that I don't understand.

The error:

```
C:/Users/puppy/Documents/ARMDevTools/SrcGBA/PaintBoyAdvance/source/paintboyadvance.c:35:14: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
   35 | bitmapfont[0].pixelsPerLetter[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
      |              ^
C:/Users/puppy/Documents/ARMDevTools/SrcGBA/PaintBoyAdvance/source/paintboyadvance.c:36:14: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
   36 | bitmapfont[1].pixelsPerLetter[] = {0x10,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x00};
      |              ^
================ READY ================
```

The source code that caused the error (minimal reproducible example):

```
struct letter{
    char PixelsPerLetter[8];
};

struct letter bitmapfont[96];
bitmapfont[0].PixelsPerLetter[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
bitmapfont[1].PixelsPerLetter[] = {0x10,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x00};


int main(void)
{
    
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell I'm not missing any semicolons at the end of the lines so I don't see why I would even need the listed characters. This is how you define each struct within the array, no? With a dot like that? That's what all the examples I've seen show and yet I get this error.

EDIT: Moving everything into main gives me a different error:

```
C:/Users/puppy/Documents/ARMDevTools/SrcGBA/PaintBoyAdvance/source/paintboyadvance.c:12:39: error: expected expression before ']' token
   12 |         bitmapfont[0].PixelsPerLetter[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
      |                                       ^
C:/Users/puppy/Documents/ARMDevTools/SrcGBA/PaintBoyAdvance/source/paintboyadvance.c:13:39: error: expected expression before ']' token
   13 |         bitmapfont[1].PixelsPerLetter[] = {0x10,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x00};
```

I don't understand this one either.

Comment: When asking questions like this in the future, or if the marked question is not the same problem, prepare a [mre].

Comment: Due to lack of MCVE it is hard to tell if your code is inside a function or not. If it is outside of any function, the linked duplicate contains the answer. In any case, there is no  member `pixelsPerLetter` but a member `PixelsPerLetter`. Identifiers in C are case sensitive after all... And also you cannot assign a value to an array like that. You can only initialize arrays with such an initializer list, but not assign a value.

Comment: Your edit fixed 2 errors but the third is still there.

Comment: You could use a compound literal to set the values of your array elements: `memcpy(&bitmapfont[0].PixelsPerLetter, (char[8]){0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}, sizeof(bitmapfont[0].PixelsPerLetter));` if you don't want to use initializer list.

Comment: `struct letter bitmapfont[96] = {{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}, {0x10,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x00}, { /* etc */ }, };`

Comment: @Gerhardh You're right, I missed that. I thought you could use lists like that any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize variables declared at file scope but you can't assign to them, because assignment is regarded as run-time code. All code executed at run-time must be located inside functions.

As mentioned you can fix this by rewriting the code to use initialization:

```
struct letter bitmapfont[96] = 
{
  [0] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00},
  [1] = {0x10,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x00},
  ...
};
```

Also this sounds like something that shouldn't be changed in run-time, so you should add `const` and ensure it gets allocated in flash.

In case you do need to change it at run-time for whatever reason, it is possible by using compound literals:

```
{
  // inside a function

  bitmapfont[0] = (struct letter){0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only *initialise* on instantiation.  You have attempted an *assignment* outside of any function - that will not work.

```
struct letter bitmapfont[96]= { {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00},
                                {0x10,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x00} } ;
```